# Spring Executors - Executing method in thread with specific index

Tags: java, spring, implementation

In my application I have a receiver which should processing messages with many threads. Sender module is putting messages on stack and receiver module is taking it from this stack. Everything works with two threads (one for sending, one for receiving). Now I want to receive messages with many threads.

Messages have some kind of group number. I need to process one group of messages in one thread (there will be more messages groups than threads). How can I handle with this?

I want to do something like this:

```
public class ReceiverExample {
    @Autowired
    Receiver receiver; 

    @Autowired 
    TaskExecutor executor;

    public void receive(){
        Msg msg = receiver.receive(); 
        int index = msg.getIndex();

        executor.execute(
                //put index ? ,
                msg
        );
    }
}
```

I'm using Spring Framework. I know I must use some kind of executor, but I can't find any good example showing my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to ensure that two `Runnable`s that have the same "message group id" are never run in parallel.

The "executor" interface has no concept of "messageGroupId", so you might need to write another class to co-ordinate this (not sure if something like this exists in a 3rd party library or anything, maybe someone could post a suggestion??)

The class below maintains one queue per thread and will ensure that tasks with the same message group Id always go on the same queue. A single thread is created for each of these queues to process the tasks... (it is not perfect, but it may be a good starting point)

```
package stack;

import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class MessageGroupTaskExecutor {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageGroupTaskExecutor.class);
    private static final long POLL_TIME = 10;

    private BlockingQueue<Runnable>[] queues;
    private Thread[] workerThreads;
    private volatile boolean stopped;
    private ThreadFactory threadFactory;

    public MessageGroupTaskExecutor(int numberOfThreads, ThreadFactory threadFactory) {
        this.threadFactory = threadFactory;
        this.queues = new BlockingQueue[numberOfThreads];
        this.workerThreads = new Thread[numberOfThreads];
    }

    public void init() {
        for (int k = 0; k < workerThreads.length; k++) {
            queues[k] = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>();
            workerThreads[k] = threadFactory.newThread(new WorkerThread(queues[k]));
            workerThreads[k].start();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Not a great impl - no way to "shutdown after all tasks finished" (at the moment...)
     */
    public void shutdown() {
        stopped = true;
        for (Thread thread : workerThreads) {
            try {
                thread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                LOG.warn("Interrupted waiting for thread to finish", e);
            }
        }
    }

    public void execute(int messageGroup, Runnable command) {
        queues[messageGroup % queues.length].add(command);
        LOG.debug("Submitted {} for message group {}", command, messageGroup);
    }

    private class WorkerThread implements Runnable {

        private BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue;

        public WorkerThread(BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue) {
            this.queue = queue;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!stopped) {
                Runnable nextJob = null;
                try {
                    nextJob = queue.poll(POLL_TIME, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    LOG.debug("Interrupted when polling queue", e);
                }

                if (nextJob != null) {
                    try {
                        LOG.debug("Got job " + nextJob);
                        nextJob.run();
                        LOG.debug("Completed " + nextJob);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        LOG.debug("Exception thrown by " + nextJob, ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, when a job is submitted via the `execute` method, the message group Id is used to select which queue to put the job on.

Worker threads will process these queues.

Here is a basic class that uses it...

```
package stack;

import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class TestIt {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestIt.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MessageGroupTaskExecutor exe = new MessageGroupTaskExecutor(5, Executors.defaultThreadFactory());

        exe.init();

        for (int k = 0; k < 100; k++) {
            int messageGroup = (int) (Math.random() * 15.0);
            exe.execute(messageGroup, new MyTask(messageGroup, k));
        }
    }

    private static class MyTask implements Runnable {
        private int mg;
        private int taskNumber;

        public MyTask(int mg, int taskNumber) {
            this.mg = mg;
            this.taskNumber = taskNumber;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            LOG.info("Doing task {} for message group {}", taskNumber, mg);
            try {
                Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random() * 500));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            LOG.info("Done task {} for message group {}", taskNumber, mg);
        }

    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks  for your idea, it helps me to develop similar, a little bit simpler solution which works fine :)